# What would happen to transfers to a contract address before creation?

Tags: contract-development, addresses

If someone transfers funds to a contract address before I create the contract, what will happen to the funds when I create the contract?

For example:

1. Get address of future contract.
2. Transfer funds.
3. Create contract.

Does the new contract get created with a positive balance? Or do the funds get cleared out?

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

If no code is associated with an address the transfer will succeed and the amount will be added to the address balance.

A contract can be created in that address later and it will have an initial balance. But the contract fallback function will not be called.